# Query by custom dates in UNIX Time

Tags: wp-query, date-time, timestamp

I actually have a custom date registered in UNIX Time in my database like this:

meta_key : custom_date
meta_value : 1322697600

and the type of the meta key is a longtext

I would like to retrieve specific post according to the year of this custom_date

I would like something like this :

```
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'custom',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
                'key'=>'custom_date',
                'value'=> '2010'
            )
);
```

Anyone knows how to convert the custom date in Date in the query and get only the year of this date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a built-in `date()` function that formats Date-objects. In your case, you would use it as follows:

```
echo date('Y', 1322697600);
```

Since you're using these query arguments to build up an array of posts, and you want to filter specifically on that, I'd recommend building a function that triggers the loop based on your desired year filter.

I have used a similar function like this one below before:

```
function check_post_date($filter_year) {

    // Load the custom_date meta field
    $custom_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_date', true );

    // Turn it into a string that only displays the year
    $custom_date_year = date('Y', $custom_date);

    // If the years equal, return true.
    if( $custom_date_year == $filter_year ) {
         return true;           
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this, you can manipulate if the loop runs for this post.

For instance, if you want to filter on the year 2010, you can write your loop like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if check_post_date('2010') : ?>

       <!-- Your single post code goes here! -->

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: And if I want to sort my query by custom date? I actually tried to find a solution to convert the date directly in the args array. Is it possible?

Comment: You can still sort your post by custom date. For your specific question, you can use the `orderby => meta_value` in your `$args`. This will sort on your custom meta key. From [the WordPress documentation for WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query): _Note that a `meta_key=keyname` must also be present in the query._

Comment: I actually also have another meta_key called country

Comment: So I used `meta_query = array( array( 'key'=> 'country', 'value'=> $country_selected ) );` but how to sort query using orderby while choosing your meta_key.

Comment: Then you should replace the `'country'` part with a variable, just like you did with the `'value'`.